# Can I dynamically build a function at runtime in c#?

Tags: c#, function, dynamic, runtime, func

Is it possible to build function at runtime in c#?

Say I have this method:

```
List<object> DoSomeWork(List<object> listOfItems, bool boolA, bool boolB)
{
   var resultsList = new List<object>();

   foreach (var value in listOfItems)
   {
      var resultOfWork = CallFunction(value);

      if (boolA)
      {
          resultOfWork = AnotherFunctionCall(resultOfWork);
      }

      if (boolB)
      {
          resultOfWork = ThirdFunctionCall(resultOfWork);
      }

      resultsList.Add(resultOfWork);
   }

   return resultsList;
}
```

Is there a way I can dynamically build a function at runtime to prevent the need to check boolA and boolB for every iteration of the loop?

In my head I'd have something that looks like this:

```
List<object> DoSomeWork(List<object> listOfItems, bool boolA, bool boolB)
{
   Func<object, object> processor = (toProcess) =>
   {
       var resultOfWork = CallFunction(toProcess);
   }

   if (boolA)
   {
       processor += { resultOfWork = AnotherFunctionCall(resultOfWork); };
   }

   if (boolB)
   {
       processor += { resultOfWork = ThirdFunctionCall(resultOfWork); };
   }

   processor += { return resultOfWork; };

   var resultsList = new List<object>();

   foreach (var value in listOfItems)
   {
      resultsList.Add(processor(value));
   }

   return resultsList;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated)
This example builds and compiles a function that varies based on the results you passed in.

```
    public static object CallFunction(object item) { return item; }
    public static object AnotherFunctionCall(object item) { return item; }
    public static object ThirdFunctionCall(object item) { return item; }

    public static MethodInfo CallFunctionMethodInfo = typeof(BuildFunction).GetMethod("CallFunction");
    public static MethodInfo AnotherFunctionCallMethodInfo = typeof(BuildFunction).GetMethod("AnotherFunctionCall");
    public static MethodInfo ThirdFunctionCallMethodInfo = typeof(BuildFunction).GetMethod("ThirdFunctionCall");

    public static Func<object, object> CreateFunc(bool boolA, bool boolB)
    {
        var objectParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var returnVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(object), "returnVar");

        var commands = new List<Expression>();

        commands.Add(
            Expression.Assign(
            returnVar,
            Expression.Call(CallFunctionMethodInfo, objectParameter)));

        if (boolA)
        {
            commands.Add(
                Expression.Assign(
                returnVar,
                Expression.Call(AnotherFunctionCallMethodInfo, returnVar)));
        }

        if (boolB)
        {
            commands.Add(
                Expression.Assign(
                returnVar,
                Expression.Call(ThirdFunctionCallMethodInfo, returnVar)));
        }

        commands.Add(returnVar);

        var body = Expression.Block(new[] { returnVar }, commands);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(body, objectParameter).Compile();
    }
```

Call this function from your code `Func<object, object> processor = CreateFunc(boolA,boolB);`

Comment: The resultant expression tree is incorrect, because you keep passing the original parameter to all three functions.

Comment: OK. I believe the updated code should work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving what you wish to achieve. You can use `Linq.Expression` to construct a function at run-time. However, since you've got only two Boolean flags, you can take a simpler approach that uses four "pre-built" function objects, like this:

```
Func<object,object> processor;
if (boolA && boolB) {
    processor = v => ThirdFunctionCall(AnotherFunctionCall(CallFunction(x)));
} else if (boolA && !boolB) {
    processor = v => AnotherFunctionCall(CallFunction(x));
} else if (!boolA && boolB) {
    processor = v => ThirdFunctionCall(CallFunction(x));
} else {
    processor = v => CallFunction(v);
}
var resultsList = listOfItems.Select(processor).ToList();
```

The bulk of the logic is in the chain of `if` conditionals, which enumerate all four possibilities for the pair `{boolA, boolB}`, and assigns the `processor` functor a lambda expression with the appropriate functionality.

Please note the absence of the explicit `foreach` loop, which can be replaced now with a LINQ call of `Select(...)` followed by `ToList()`.

Comment: Sure, I had considered this approach but what's putting me off is that in my real problem `CallFunction`, `AnotherFunctionCall` and `ThirdFunctionCall` are all semi-complex chunks of inline logic. I suppose I could always pull them out into separate functions. I'm interested in what you've said about `Linq.Expression`, how could I this to solve my problem? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @psand2286 Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7708917/335858) that illustrates the concept.